# Why do we call teams "parties"?

Tags: terminology

I tried to search on dictionary but seems the term "party" is used in videogames "out of context".

> Party: a social gathering, as of invited guests at a private home, for conversation, refreshments, entertainment, etc.

It seems to have nothing to do with a RPG Party (maybe in a loose interpretation). Seems that someone at some point just started to use that word and **people liked the word for that use**. Recluting someone ( `Hei join the party!`) into your group to go killing a boss is not exactly the same as a social gathering at your home.. or maybe yes? at least you are going to boss' home (uninvited).

Was that a carryover from tabletop games (see comment here)?

Comment: From what I understand, teams play in "party games" (like Smash Brothers, Mario Cart, a lot of Nintendo games actually...), and that's kind of where the term party came from in regards to a team. I think it's just found its way into other games that aren't necessarily "party" style games, but teamwork games as well.

Comment: I assumed it was a carryover from tabletop games that have used the term "Adventuring party" since the 70's...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of "party" you have found is only the first, most used, and best known definition of the word. It's the definition that is closely tied to celebration and fun. In short, it's a party!

There are other definitions, such as a political party, which is (likely) quite the opposite of fun.

[**Here**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20party) are two other definitions which would fit the traditional RPG party:

> - a group of people taking part in a particular activity or trip.

Obviously, taking down a boss is an activity, and it often involves a trip to the boss' lair.

> - a person or people forming one side in an agreement or dispute.

In this case: the hero's party vs. the bad guys' party.

Answer (score 6):

What you wanted is another of the meaning of the word

> a group of people taking part in a particular activity or trip.

Another [source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/party).

Comment: that opens a italian google page to me :( (I'm In italy so I'm not seeing your exact page).